# Creating a footer using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been trying really hard to do this but I'm really y confused. I trying to create the footer of this site without using **floats**, with **flex**. Basically, I have three sets of `<ul>`, one for *Navigation*, one for *Follow Us*, and another one for *Contact*. Again, I know how to do this with regular css using floats, the challenge is my flex, not good enough.

[image]

Comment: What are those `<ul>` has to do with footer?

Comment: It is a footer of a website were the HTML was done using `<ul><li></li></ul>`.  I'm not talking about the `<footer>` tag if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: This shouldn't be hard. By the way, what output do you expect when the screen is too narrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A div was added in order to group each list in a different container. Making the `div`s the only flex items.

```
<footer> 
  <div>
    <h2 class="footer__headline">Navigation</h2>
    <ul class="footer__list">
      <li>nav 1</li>
      <li>nav 2</li>
      <li>nav 3</li>
      <li>nav 4</li>
      <li>nav 5</li>
      <li>nav 6</li>
      <li>nav 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="footer__headline">Follow Us</h2>
    <ul class="footer__list">
      <li>social 1</li>
      <li>social 2</li>
      <li>social 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="footer__headline">Contact</h2>
    <ul class="footer__list">
      <li>Adress</li>
      <li>Phone</li>
      <li>Email</li>
      <li>Website</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

On CSS, all you have to do is apply on the footer `display:flex` and `justify-content`. `justify-content` will align the list's containers depending on the attribute (space-between, space-around, center, etc) used, in this case `space-around`, which will assign an equal space on each side of the flex items. You could also use `margins` to separate the container. After having all the content arranged, we only have to remove the padding and default style from the `ul`s

```
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.footer__headline {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

.footer__list {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This works well except it is not fully responsive - it the user's device is too narrow to show all three columns on one line they will squish up and not be very readable. Adding flex-wrap: wrap; to the footer should solve this.

Comment: Indeed, `flex-wrap` would help to arrange the content for narrow screens, however, that would be up to him, how he'd like to show his information on different screen sizes.

Comment: Agreed - and responsive wasn't asked for in the question -  it's just another aspect of flex which makes life easier (and gives a result similar to floats which were mentioned) so I thought it worth pointing to.

Comment: @VictorSantizo My CSS wasn't working because the order in which the flex items were layout in the flex container was wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

do this to make responsive:

`

```
@media(max-width: 500px){

  footer{
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, You just have to use display : flex & Justify-content : Space-between
here is the code for you to better understand

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Good Luck</title>
<style>
  footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
</style>
</head>
 <body>
  <footer>
    <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li>G</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>H</li>
    <li>I</li>
    <li>J</li>
  </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>'
```

Comment: This answer goes part way to answering the question but it is not fully responsive - if the user's device is too narrow to show everything on one line the last column(s) will get cut off.